# How to handle this BACKGROUND case in Behave BDD

Tags: bdd, python-behave

I have just started to use Python & Behave BDD for automation.

One of my test suite includes these part:

```
0) After login on the web page
1) to create a new profile 
2) to view the created profile in the profile list. 
3) to update the created profile 
4) to have the profile deleted.
```

Now I am trying to put all these in one feature file, something as:

```
Feature: Profile behaviour testing

Background: User login
...

Scenario: creating new profile
...

Scenario: viewing created profile
...

Scenario: updating generated profile
...

Scenario: deleting created profile 
....
```

But the issue is the background part applies to each individual scenario, that for each scenario, it starts from login session.

Is there a way it happens only once ?

Thanks,

Chun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Background keyword is really more syntax sugar than anything, applying the steps in Background to every scenario in the feature. If you want to only log the user in a single time, you can try managing that in the context object.

Given this behave structure:

```
├── behave.ini
└── features
    ├── environment.py
    ├── login-once.feature
    └── steps
        └── steps.py
```

behave.ini:

```
[behave]
stdout_capture = false
stderr_capture = false
log_capture = false
```

login-once.feature:

```
Feature: User Login only actually happens once

    Background: User Login
        Given the user is logged in

    Scenario: User clicks Home
        When the user clicks the Home button
        Then the Home page is shown

    Scenario: User clicks About
        When the user clicks the About button
        Then the About page is shown
```

environment.py:

```
# Behave has an interesting page/heap structure behind the scenes
# that obfuscates what is and isn't in the context object.
# This class is instantiated in the before_all function and used
# to assign values, so that they persist across scenario tests

class Holder(object):
    pass


def before_all(context):
    context.holder = Holder()


def before_feature(context, feature):
    context.holder.logged_in = False
```

steps.py

```
from behave import given, then, when


@given('the user is logged in')
def user_logged_in(context):
    if context.holder.logged_in is True:
        print("\t\tThe user is already logged in, will not log in again")
    else:
        print("\t\tLogging user in for the first time")
        context.holder.logged_in = True

@when('the user clicks the {button} button')
def user_clicks_button(context, button):
    print(f"\t\tThe user clicked the {button} button")

@then('the {page} page is shown')
def page_is_shown(context, page):
    print(f"\t\tThe {page} page is being shown")
```

When I run behave now, I get the following output:

```
$ behave -f plain
Feature: User Login only actually happens once
  Background: User Login

  Scenario: User clicks Home
        Logging user in for the first time
    Given the user is logged in ... passed in 0.000s
        The user clicked the Home button
    When the user clicks the Home button ... passed in 0.000s
        The Home page is being shown
    Then the Home page is shown ... passed in 0.000s

  Scenario: User clicks About
        The user is already logged in, will not log in again
    Given the user is logged in ... passed in 0.000s
        The user clicked the About button
    When the user clicks the About button ... passed in 0.000s
        The About page is being shown
    Then the About page is shown ... passed in 0.000s

1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
2 scenarios passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
6 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m0.001s
```